# Getting Visual Studio Environment Variable Programmatically in C/C++ in VS?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, variables

Is it possible to get the value of $(ProjectName)  programatically in Visual Studio?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    char *pValue;
    size_t len;
    errno_t err = _dupenv_s(&pValue, &len, "$(ProjectName)");
    if (err) return -1;
    printf("ProjectName = %s\n", pValue);
    free(pValue);
}
```

I have tried to do this , but it doesn't work. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: who can help me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It's not an OS environment variable, but a variable in the Visual Studio editor itself.  Your program would have to be a Visual Studio extension to access it, or the build process could embed the variable in the source code, perhaps with a pre-build script that runs:

```
echo #define PROJECTNAME $(ProjectName) >project.h`
```